# How to programmatically add files to AWS S3 Bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to write a lambda function that capture an image of my PCs webcam feed every time a trigger occurs. I want to programmatically add them to an S3 bucket without overriding them with the same key (like "image.jpg"). What's the best way to do something where the **filename is incremented** every time the function is called (ex: image1.jpg, image2.jpg, etc)? Note: I am using Boto3 to upload to S3 buckets.

Comment: What have you tried and that did not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an easy way to do this is to add date-time to the name of the image while storing/uploading to s3 , with this you always will have a new key name in your bucket. Code given below will do your work.

```
import boto3
import datetime

i = datetime.datetime.now()
ptr=str(i)  
smg='group1'+ptr+'.jpeg'

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file('local/file/group1.jpeg', 'bucket_name', smg)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can store a current counter in DynamoDB or in parameter store.

Or just use a timestamp with enough resolution and be done with it.